# How to make fmpsl files open in Filemaker Advanced 17 rather than Filemaker Advanced 16?

Tags: macos, filemaker, finder

I'm creating Filemaker snapshot links to add to a project.
When I double click on the *.fmpsl files the Finder is opening FileMaker Advanced 16 even though the latest version I have on the system is FileMaker Advanced 17.

How would I make Finder open FileMaker Advanced 17 instead of FileMaker Advanced 16 when double clicking on *.fmpsl files? (preferably via the command line if possible.)

Comment: Can we assume this is on macOS?

Comment: Yes ... Sorry for that ... I'll add the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for posting this. I knew the default installation of FMPA 17 on macOS did not properly associate the application with the `fmp:` URL protocol. I wasn't aware the same was true for changing the default application to open a Snapshot Link file.

I know of two ways to fix this:

1. Do `Get Info` on the FMPSL file and under `Open with:` select the *other* `Filemaker Pro Advanced.app` item in the drop-down. This is a little difficult, since they have the same name and icon, but it is not the one currently selected. Then press `Change All…`.
2. Download the [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) preference pane from Rubicode. After installing, go to the `Extensions` tab and associate the `fmpsl` extension with the correct application. This is also how you can change the default application to answer a `fmp:` URL protocol call (credit to [SeedCode](http://www.seedcode.com/pmwiki/index.php?n=DayBackForFileMaker.FMPURL)).